# Export To XLS (keeping html table format) from javascript - Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, safari

I have an html table :

http://postimg.org/image/fzgf635pv/

And i have code to export it to and xls file. All works good in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari browser, file would save as Unknown and no file extension, also it's losing the table format.

I know the download attribute it's not compatible with Safari browser and i've tried to find a solution but nothing came up. 
Any ideas?

(export to xls code:
http://postimg.org/image/9t7unf1b1/
)

Comment: Did you got the answer for this question?

Comment: No answer, after looking more into it we concluded that there is no way to do this (Safari browser restriction)

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Can anyone help me on this question???